# How to repopulate SQLFORM fields in an edit form page in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to write an edit form function where the fields in the displayed form on the page are already populated with the corresponding entry.

I have two different databases that store the data for the form. I have tried running a query on the databases to check which entry matches the form id for the entry that is being edited, but that returns a value of none.

```py
def edit():
    q1 = ((db.form1 == request.args(0))
    q2 = ((db.form2 == request.args(0))
    form = SQLFORM.factory(db.form1, db.form2)
    form.vars = q1
    form.vars = q2
    return dict(form=form)
```

I expected for the query to return the record that matches the form id for that record, but it returns NULL.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. You mention two databases but instead show two tables in the same database. You are querying both tables using the same record ID (i.e., `request.args(0)`), which seems odd -- is it really the case that related records in each table have identical record IDs? It would help if you showed more detail about your real code. Also, note that there are several problems with the above code. The queries are just `Query` objects, not records. You cannot just assign a record to `form.vars`, and the second assignment overwrites the first.

Comment: The two tables are two separate databases. I use `SQLFORM.factory` to combine the two into one form, so a record has matching ids. I was able to accomplish what i need using `SQLFORM.grid()`. Thank you for your help and reccomendations. @Anthony

Comment: `db` is a single `DAL` object representing a connection to a single database, so the code as shown above cannot represent two databases. I suppose you can attempt to maintain common IDs in this way, but it is not good design, as nothing enforces equality of IDs (e.g., any external operations on the databases could throw things off).